# Building a web service with WCF for usage by existing Java client using WSDL

Tags: wcf, wsdl, contract-first

I have an existing Java client that I need to build a web service for in .NET 4.0. The interface is already defined with a WSDL file so I created a class library and generated the server side stub using [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) (I also tried svcutil without success). WSCF.blue takes care of the references and adding the files (great tool :-)) so I only replaced the generated System.NotImplementedException with some code. Then I hosted the result in an ASP.NET development server.

I guess I need some additional step since I get the famous "The contract name 'WsdlWebService.IHello' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Hello'." when looking the service up in the browser (see [WCF Contract Name 'IMyService' could not be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691746/wcf-contract-name-imyservice-could-not-be-found)). But here the is a ServiceContractAttribute of which I expect that it does the job.

I would appreciate if someone could point to what I'm missing...

This is the generated interface and implementation:

```
    namespace WsdlWebService
    {
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://webservice.com", ConfigurationName="IHello")]
        public interface IHello
        {
            [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://webservice.com/IHello/helloName", ReplyAction="http://webservice.com/IHello/helloNameResponse")]
            [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
            [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="helloNameReturn")]
            string helloName(string name);
        }

        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute(InstanceContextMode=System.ServiceModel.InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode=System.ServiceModel.ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
        public class Hello : IHello
        {
            public virtual string helloName(string name)
            {
                return "Hello world from (via wsdl extraced server) " + name + "!";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
          <service name="WsdlWebService.Hello"
                 behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                 contract="WsdlWebService.IHello"/>
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
               binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
          </service>
        </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing since I have not had that error, but I noticed you set the `ConfigurationName = "IHello"` on your service contract, but you're referring to it as "WsdlWebService.IHello" in the configuration. I would at least check if the configuration name is atomic or still only part of the namespace.

Comment: Thanks DonAndre, that was the missing detail, I can now see the webserver in the browser and get to the WSDL. Unfortunately I found out that the WCF service is not exactly the same as the original Java based server because I get a "no endpoint listening" error when accessing it with the same client. I you know good resources that could help I'll be much obliged.

Comment: Sorry no idea. Maybe try to generate a new java client with the same technology and see if it's any different from the point of service access.